# Redirect to tab in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, webforms, tabs, response.redirect

If I put code it will go to the view below

(Please click link to view picture)

Response.Redirect(Report.aspx);

[image: report]

I want to redirect to the tab called "number of booking" how do i do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Do you want show a DB ?

Comment: I want to show the gridview in Number of Bookings tab

Answer (score 0):

Put below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#tabs').tabs({ selected: 1 })
        });
    </script>
```

here

0: first tab

1:second tab
etc

Also you can write in pageLoad of javascript event if you have partial post back in page with update panel